# 502 Bad Gateway with nginx + apache + subversion + ssl (SVN COPY)

Tags: svn, apache, ssl, nginx

I'm having a problem running Apache + Subversion with SSL behind an Nginx proxy and I'm hoping someone might have the answer. I've scoured google for hours looking for the answer to my problem and can't seem to figure it out. What I'm seeing are "502 (Bad Gateway)" errors when trying to MOVE or COPY using subversion; however, checkouts and commits work fine. Here are the relevant parts (I think) of the nginx and apache config files in question:

**Nginx**

```
upstream subversion_hosts {
    server 127.0.0.1:80;
}


server {
        listen       x.x.x.x:80;
        server_name  hostname;

        access_log   /srv/log/nginx/http.access_log main;
        error_log    /srv/log/nginx/http.error_log info;

        # redirect all requests to https
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://hostname/$1 redirect;
}

# HTTPS server
server {
        listen       x.x.x.x:443;
        server_name  hostname;

        passenger_enabled    on;
        root /path/to/rails/root;

        access_log   /srv/log/nginx/ssl.access_log main;
        error_log    /srv/log/nginx/ssl.error_log info;

        ssl                  on;
        ssl_certificate      server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key  server.key;

        add_header Front-End-Https on;

        location /svn {
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                set $fixed_destination $http_destination;
                if ( $http_destination ~* ^https(.*)$ )
                {
                    set $fixed_destination http$1;
                }
                proxy_set_header Destination $fixed_destination;

                proxy_pass http://subversion_hosts;
        }
}
```

**Apache**

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # in order to support COPY and MOVE, etc -  over https (443),
        # ServerName _must_ be the same as the nginx servername
        # http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracNginxRecipe
        ServerName hostname
        UseCanonicalName on

        <Location /svn>
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath "/srv/svn"
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
                Satisfy any
                # Some config omitted ...
        </Location>

        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/subversion_error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/subversion_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

From what I could tell while researching this problem, the server name has to match on both the apache server as well as the nginx server, which I've done. Additionally, this problem seems to stick around even if I change the configuration to use http only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the cause of my problem was not the proxy between nginx and apache, but rather was an issue with Apache itself.

What I didn't mention in the original question was what was in the `# Some config omitted`. This block contained the following:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Redmine SVN Repository"
Require valid-user
PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
```

For suberversion, I'm controlling user access using [Redmine's](http://www.redmine.org) authentication handler. After turning options on and off and narrowing down the problem, I learned that their authentication module is not thread-safe. I was running into the error because Apache was using the Worker MPM. Switching to the Prefork MPM (`sudo aptitude install apache2-mpm-prefork` in Ubuntu) resolved the issue.

Answer (score 12):

The previous solutions did not work for me, I had to change the nginx configuration and add the following in the `location` block, before the `proxy_pass` directive:

```
set $fixed_destination $http_destination;
if ( $http_destination ~* ^https(.*)$ ) {
    set $fixed_destination http$1;
}
proxy_set_header Destination $fixed_destination;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Comment: This does work but would you please explain what this code actually does?

Comment: The Destination header is used for COPY and MOVE methods (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2518#page-54). If we serve SSL/TLS with nginx and use Apache with mod_dav_svn as backend, the latter does not know about the https:// URI. With this snippet we strip the s from the https in the Destination header to match what Apache/Subversion is serving. The Host header is set to the original HTTP_HOST value from the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 9):

I faced this exact problem today.

Adding the following in the apache2 configuration fixed it:

`RequestHeader edit Destination ^https http early`

Cheers,
  Ignace M

---

Source:

- https://secure.bonkabonka.com/blog/2008/01/04/nginx_fronting_for_subversion.htm

Comment: I had tried that in the past, but figured it was worth a shot again. Unfortunately for me, that did not do the trick.

Comment: i added this line but it not works for years. today i removed this line and it works now

Comment: While this is a working suggestion, this is NOT a correct suggestion. More correct is to teach nginx to send fixed Destination header according to changed scheme.

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I was using **RouixSVN** and I only had to **clear** the SVN **authentication** data on my computer and log in again and it worked. Hope it helps someone else.